# Can you tell me how to get rotated android virtual device back to normal?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

May I know how to rotate the rotated android automotive virtual device in the forward direction as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Ctrl + (F11, F12, etc...) I tried several methods, but all failed.

[image]

In addition, there is no response when pressing the `Rotate Right` and `Rotate Left` buttons corresponding to the picture immediately above.

Comment: If you have checked the settings then a restart is usually successful.

Comment: @SolarMike           
Thanks for the reply.            
But can you explain in more detail what setting to check and restart?

Comment: "Restart" aka power off then back on.

Comment: @SolarMike
Thank you for your kind reply, but have you tried the SDK? It is impossible to solve by executing such a simple on/off.

Comment: If you have tried the "simple on/off" then you should have mentioned that in your question, along with anything else you have tried.

Comment: @SolarMike
yes thank you for your answer. However, I think it would be more helpful to receive an answer from someone who has developed S/W in the Android Studio environment. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to undock the emulator from android studio then one can easily rotate it.

go to `File -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator`
and uncheck the `Launch in a tool windows` and the restart the android studio.

[image]

Comment: @강경모 if this has solved your problem, please click on the checkmark icon bellow score number to make this answer as accepted answer.

Comment: This fixed my issues. Thumbs up!